# Listview only filling with first item

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a Listview that gets its contents from an async task, but only the first item is actually getting placed into the Listview.

My xml for the activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/portfolioTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:text="Your Portfolio"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                </TextView>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sortTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:text="Sorting Options:"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                </TextView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/portfolioSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/portfolio_array"

                        />


                </LinearLayout>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/allYourBeersList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="0px"
            android:divider="@null"

            >
        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The async task is:

```
public class PortfolioGetAllBeers extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public PortfolioGetAllBeers (Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting beers");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<ShortBeerInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<ShortBeerInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("beer");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String beerID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                String breweryID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("breweryID");


                int count = i + 1;

                beer = count + ". " + beer;


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID , breweryID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                ShortBeerInfoAdapter adapter1 = new ShortBeerInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        ShortBeerInfo o=(ShortBeerInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String tempID = o.id;
                        String tempBrewID = o.brewery;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, tempID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        //get beer details from id

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, BeerPage2.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", tempID);
                        myIntent.putExtra("breweryID", tempBrewID);
                        c.startActivity(myIntent);


                    }
                });




            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Why I am confused is because my json is coming back with more then one result:

```
[{"beer":"#9","rate":"3","id":"hB0QeO","breweryID":"qIqpZc"},{"beer":"120 Minute IPA","rate":"5","id":"EWlB8A","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"2011 Pere Jacques","rate":"4","id":"7EhKvb","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"2xIPA","rate":"3","id":"kZsjqY","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"312 Urban Wheat Ale","rate":"3","id":"EaoR0H","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"471 Double IPA Small Batch","rate":"4","id":"j9cp5e","breweryID":"IImUD9"},{"beer":"5 Golden Rings","rate":"2","id":"tRFIN3","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"beer":"60 Minute IPA","rate":"3","id":"TACnR2","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"75 Minute IPA","rate":"5","id":"ovCoQh","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"90 Minute IPA","rate":"5","id":"qqTzHb","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"\u00a7ucaba (Abacus)","rate":"5","id":"GWY6vH","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"beer":"Admiral IPA","rate":"3","id":"nHYjdl","breweryID":"OYQA8m"},{"beer":"Agave Wheat","rate":"3","id":"6AcqY6","breweryID":"IImUD9"},{"beer":"Alimony Ale","rate":"0","id":"G7kmvt","breweryID":"P1I1gt"},{"beer":"Allagash Black","rate":"4","id":"z77hjQ","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Allagash Dubbel","rate":"3","id":"KzHweV","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Allagash Fluxus 2013","rate":"3","id":"SlMu4Q","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Allagash Four","rate":"4","id":"0mttNd","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Allagash Victoria Ale","rate":"4","id":"JLBMnT","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Allagash White","rate":"4","id":"Q8hjek","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"American Amber Ale","rate":"3","id":"3SvZ4H","breweryID":"X0l98q"},{"beer":"American Pilsner","rate":"3","id":"67Hcxk","breweryID":"xcKkLh"},{"beer":"Anchor Steam","rate":"3","id":"Uiol9p","breweryID":"6PBXvz"},{"beer":"Angels Share","rate":"5","id":"ikoDPe","breweryID":"9x7wNn"},{"beer":"Aprihop","rate":"4","id":"qV0bBx","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Arrogant Bastard Ale","rate":"3","id":"qlwwem","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Aventinus Weizen-Eisbock","rate":"4","id":"avMkil","breweryID":"FQLVgV"},{"beer":"B.O.R.I.S. The Crusher Oatmeal-Imperial Stout","rate":"5","id":"Tzy7eJ","breweryID":"w5OOQ5"},{"beer":"Back in Black","rate":"3","id":"UD5Sm4","breweryID":"EdRcIs"},{"beer":"Balt Altbier","rate":"3","id":"dR7EQg","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"beer":"Baltic Thunder","rate":"3","id":"DCwAKJ","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Bass Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"r5GwCX","breweryID":"X2Qkw1"},{"beer":"Belgian Abbey Dubbel","rate":"3","id":"YkoqCD","breweryID":"M5zcKb"},{"beer":"Big DIPA","rate":"4","id":"aP9faI","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Black & Blue","rate":"3","id":"tL3vdf","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Black Cannon","rate":"3","id":"f9WbNU","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Blackwing Lager","rate":"3","id":"ISXK3w","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"beer":"Blue Moon Belgian White","rate":"3","id":"dDXOEp","breweryID":"avMkil"},{"beer":"Br\u00e4u Weisse","rate":"4","id":"L6f8QM","breweryID":"QKdFk2"},{"beer":"Brawler","rate":"2","id":"czwGMM","breweryID":"jwWiTH"},{"beer":"Breakfast Stout","rate":"4","id":"9na4NR","breweryID":"Idm5Y5"},{"beer":"Bronx Pale Ale","rate":"4","id":"yDHpxQ","breweryID":"V0wvf7"},{"beer":"Bud Light","rate":"2","id":"dimtrs","breweryID":"BznahA"},{"beer":"Burton Baton","rate":"4","id":"em9Lxc","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Caldera IPA","rate":"3","id":"kMlOin","breweryID":"iL3Juq"},{"beer":"Centennial IPA","rate":"3","id":"rAHla4","breweryID":"Idm5Y5"},{"beer":"Cerveza Sol","rate":"2","id":"4ap3mq","breweryID":"UWBCmm"},{"beer":"Chateau Jiahu","rate":"4","id":"bFOmYH","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Chocolate Stout","rate":"4","id":"93XbpS","breweryID":"X0l98q"},{"beer":"Circus Boy","rate":"3","id":"JQCCB0","breweryID":"qIqpZc"},{"beer":"Corona Extra","rate":"3","id":"ujPz4L","breweryID":"wadu38"},{"beer":"Corona Light","rate":"3","id":"u7U2Ga","breweryID":"wadu38"},{"beer":"Cr\u00e8me Br\u00fbl\u00e9e Imperial Milk Stout","rate":"4","id":"Kax7jD","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Cricket Hill Hopnotic","rate":"1","id":"FCGb3K","breweryID":"U0vh9j"},{"beer":"Curieux","rate":"4","id":"T6rZqg","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Cutlass","rate":"3","id":"1KVlP0","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Dales Pale Ale","rate":"4","id":"iT9pf4","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"beer":"Delirium Tremens","rate":"3","id":"siPwY9","breweryID":"8eyXN7"},{"beer":"Dogtoberfest","rate":"3","id":"IgdWNj","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Don De Dieu","rate":"3","id":"i6yPHf","breweryID":"llbEuB"},{"beer":"Dos Equis Amber Lager","rate":"2","id":"s5lxSd","breweryID":"UWBCmm"},{"beer":"Double Dog Double Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"r9nypM","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Double Jack Imperial IPA","rate":"5","id":"sUL1uy","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"beer":"Double Stout","rate":"3","id":"uVJmkY","breweryID":"c67gGy"},{"beer":"Double Wide I.P.A.","rate":"4","id":"LKzaHC","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"beer":"DreamWeaver Wheat Ale","rate":"3","id":"0aUaXd","breweryID":"n5QFi2"},{"beer":"Drifter Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"HfAvcD","breweryID":"8wcv7h"},{"beer":"Duck-Rabbit Milk Stout","rate":"4","id":"C6EUeD","breweryID":"rBxNNF"},{"beer":"Duckpin Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"17OQHF","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"beer":"Etrusca","rate":"4","id":"ffEc4d","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Euforia Toffee Nut","rate":"4","id":"o4ENUL","breweryID":"TVgBWg"},{"beer":"Fat Tire","rate":"2","id":"tuqTtX","breweryID":"Jt43j7"},{"beer":"Festina Peche","rate":"3","id":"Gf9h6p","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Finestkind IPA","rate":"3","id":"3RFxH6","breweryID":"v0MKXA"},{"beer":"Franziskaner Hefe-Weissbier Hell  \/ Franziskaner C","rate":"3","id":"ZhGbaC","breweryID":"o5vGy8"},{"beer":"Furious","rate":"4","id":"qRuupG","breweryID":"cPRfoj"},{"beer":"FV13","rate":"4","id":"xv9fS8","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"beer":"Gemini","rate":"3","id":"L8oWyF","breweryID":"7VPQrN"},{"beer":"GKnight","rate":"3","id":"69R1Vd","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"beer":"Gold Ale","rate":"3","id":"bIk08d","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Golden Monkey","rate":"4","id":"UfxKKB","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Gonzo Imperial Porter","rate":"3","id":"kkcQtN","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Guinness Draught","rate":"3","id":"StkEiv","breweryID":"HaPdSL"},{"beer":"Hardcore IPA","rate":"3","id":"7RaQWJ","breweryID":"wfAwfx"},{"beer":"Harvest","rate":"3","id":"9Pj2Cr","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Harvest Moon Pumpkin Ale","rate":"3","id":"Oa5lvx","breweryID":"avMkil"},{"beer":"Heart of Darkness","rate":"3","id":"KvSwJR","breweryID":"qIqpZc"},{"beer":"Hefeweizen","rate":"3","id":"7Xn4wJ","breweryID":"P2xdU4"},{"beer":"Heifer-in-Wheat","rate":"3","id":"4MyOgi","breweryID":"REDaIN"},{"beer":"Heineken","rate":"3","id":"eGtqKZ","breweryID":"robMSl"},{"beer":"Heinnieweisse Weissebeir","rate":"3","id":"RhmCRd","breweryID":"9BPs2d"},{"beer":"Hell or High Watermelon","rate":"4","id":"VNqOKH","breweryID":"EdRcIs"},{"beer":"Helles Lager","rate":"3","id":"MSdXm6","breweryID":"D3A2mu"},{"beer":"Hellhound On My Ale","rate":"4","id":"ALDE5Q","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Hellrazer","rate":"3","id":"yJ1zJK","breweryID":"TVgBWg"},{"beer":"Hennepin Saison Ale","rate":"4","id":"RsXBB4","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"beer":"Hercules Double IPA","rate":"4","id":"xHovlT","breweryID":"I8WZv2"},{"beer":"Honey Weiss","rate":"3","id":"YgHnZO","breweryID":"ZDghkK"},{"beer":"Honker's Ale","rate":"3","id":"TEG3J9","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Hop Heathen Imperial Black Ale","rate":"3","id":"bMXin5","breweryID":"w5OOQ5"},{"beer":"Hop Stoopid","rate":"3","id":"Pni8Jo","breweryID":"nLsoQ9"},{"beer":"Hop Wallop","rate":"3","id":"b58sGA","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"HopDevil","rate":"3","id":"IzTjAm","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Hopfen-Weisse","rate":"5","id":"wXHOmA","breweryID":"FQLVgV"},{"beer":"Hops Infusion","rate":"3","id":"6nkcOK","breweryID":"a57dkm"},{"beer":"Hopsecutioner","rate":"4","id":"Rfe5aM","breweryID":"DPLTAJ"},{"beer":"Hoptober","rate":"3","id":"n1bFMy","breweryID":"Jt43j7"},{"beer":"Horseshoe Bend Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"Uvuoay","breweryID":"xcKkLh"},{"beer":"Illinois","rate":"3","id":"PZbw01","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Imperial IPA","rate":"3","id":"WT6hkF","breweryID":"TR98tr"},{"beer":"Imperial Pumpkin Ale","rate":"4","id":"LRCEhC","breweryID":"a57dkm"},{"beer":"Imperial Russian Stout","rate":"0","id":"pD5RiK","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Imperial Stout","rate":"4","id":"IqPdv8","breweryID":"Idm5Y5"},{"beer":"India Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"fu2qgB","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Indian Brown Ale","rate":"3","id":"AZI8ib","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"International Arms Race","rate":"2","id":"aX0e6r","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"IPA","rate":"3","id":"iLlMCb","breweryID":"nLsoQ9"},{"beer":"Italian Strong Ale","rate":"5","id":"9S5ObB","breweryID":"wAdTKf"},{"beer":"Judgement Day","rate":"3","id":"Gwo4rP","breweryID":"9x7wNn"},{"beer":"Just the Tip","rate":"3","id":"ekhzhU","breweryID":"rKXfsB"},{"beer":"Kellerweis","rate":"3","id":"JVv3qI","breweryID":"nHLlnK"},{"beer":"Killian's Irish Red","rate":"3","id":"FXGCOG","breweryID":"avMkil"},{"beer":"La Torpille","rate":"3","id":"gghCq9","breweryID":"6DG1qh"},{"beer":"Lancaster Milk Stout","rate":"3","id":"aZtMd7","breweryID":"VGDfKl"},{"beer":"Little Sumpin' Sumpin'","rate":"4","id":"svXHfu","breweryID":"nLsoQ9"},{"beer":"Local 2","rate":"3","id":"vpdrzj","breweryID":"4OBVPn"},{"beer":"Loose Cannon","rate":"3","id":"Bt79WS","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Lucky 13","rate":"3","id":"CWwxeR","breweryID":"nLsoQ9"},{"beer":"Lucky 7 Porter","rate":"3","id":"a6XiKI","breweryID":"Ysh6PO"},{"beer":"M\u00e4rzen","rate":"4","id":"zomWCT","breweryID":"P2xdU4"},{"beer":"M\u00fcnchner Sommer","rate":"5","id":"TbP3By","breweryID":"4rlPFf"},{"beer":"Mad Elf Ale","rate":"4","id":"ZRzruY","breweryID":"n5QFi2"},{"beer":"Mad King\u2019s Weiss","rate":"3","id":"5JQA4h","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Mana Wheat","rate":"3","id":"fem70X","breweryID":"fwCFE4"},{"beer":"Matilda","rate":"5","id":"uKquc0","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Maui Coconut Porter","rate":"3","id":"sNQLDD","breweryID":"fwCFE4"},{"beer":"Merry Monks","rate":"3","id":"gz4uZ6","breweryID":"a57dkm"},{"beer":"Midas Touch","rate":"5","id":"YFZKZA","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Midshipman Mild","rate":"3","id":"eEjA64","breweryID":"OYQA8m"},{"beer":"Mild Winter","rate":"3","id":"hrhfc1","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Milk Stout Nitro","rate":"3","id":"gtaIQr","breweryID":"Ro08YF"},{"beer":"Miller Lite","rate":"1","id":"KJIjyd","breweryID":"MWi5Kp"},{"beer":"Mischief","rate":"3","id":"5A7pI0","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"beer":"Misery Bay IPA","rate":"2","id":"uSxQME","breweryID":"LHQ79n"},{"beer":"Mongo Double IPA","rate":"4","id":"9tIw2j","breweryID":"ayEBYP"},{"beer":"Monumental IPA","rate":"3","id":"kckAgC","breweryID":"9FwufS"},{"beer":"Moo Thunder Stout","rate":"3","id":"D4Ka8l","breweryID":"9BPs2d"},{"beer":"Moonglow Weizenbock","rate":"4","id":"DOrgPb","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"My Antonia","rate":"3","id":"OyeqOI","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Namaste","rate":"3","id":"1INeXj","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Narragansett Lager","rate":"2","id":"lBKttb","breweryID":"mGqkXE"},{"beer":"National Bohemian","rate":"2","id":"ssQJcb","breweryID":"AKyyYN"},{"beer":"Newcastle Werewolf","rate":"2","id":"xzED0r","breweryID":"Qutakc"},{"beer":"Noble Rot","rate":"4","id":"tEpzX3","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Nommo Dubbel","rate":"3","id":"WzJmsi","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"beer":"Nugget Nectar","rate":"3","id":"x8H3l7","breweryID":"n5QFi2"},{"beer":"Oak Barrel Stout","rate":"3","id":"JdJXIl","breweryID":"xG9JyI"},{"beer":"Oat Imperial Oatmeal Stout","rate":"4","id":"1UmxNj","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Old Chub","rate":"3","id":"KmsdoV","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"beer":"Old Guardian Oak-Smoked","rate":"4","id":"Pwkvsq","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Old Man Winter","rate":"3","id":"X60E3Q","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Old Pro","rate":"4","id":"SS2uWf","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"beer":"Old Rasputin","rate":"4","id":"CfJ0cK","breweryID":"yLBNrD"},{"beer":"Old Ruffian","rate":"3","id":"AqEUBQ","breweryID":"I8WZv2"},{"beer":"Old Scratch Amber Lager","rate":"4","id":"N4LF2o","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Olde School Barleywine","rate":"5","id":"YDBgUE","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Ommegang Abbey Ale","rate":"4","id":"jYBtXz","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"beer":"Ommegang BPA","rate":"3","id":"N101SS","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"beer":"Otis","rate":"2","id":"uTPvQK","breweryID":"7VPQrN"},{"beer":"Ozzy","rate":"4","id":"3te24V","breweryID":"YytkpO"},{"beer":"Pabst Blue Ribbon","rate":"2","id":"pDKyvz","breweryID":"AKyyYN"},{"beer":"Pale Ale","rate":"3","id":"cdkpyx","breweryID":"nHLlnK"},{"beer":"Palo Santo Marron","rate":"5","id":"7LrYr1","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Pangaea","rate":"4","id":"Oq4XtM","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Pearl Jam Twenty Faithful Ale","rate":"3","id":"6IjMIK","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Peeper","rate":"3","id":"KdKlo9","breweryID":"xgrmyW"},{"beer":"Phin ","rate":"3","id":"cWMMWU","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Porter","rate":"3","id":"bZub8V","breweryID":"9FwufS"},{"beer":"Porter Pounder","rate":"3","id":"h5zbGr","breweryID":"pqSkmD"},{"beer":"Positive Contact","rate":"3","id":"eAvRRc","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Powder Monkey","rate":"2","id":"PbHXnC","breweryID":"OYQA8m"},{"beer":"Pumkin Ale","rate":"4","id":"zpyLEw","breweryID":"tNDKBY"},{"beer":"Pumking","rate":"4","id":"iHEJZm","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"beer":"Pumpkin Ale","rate":"3","id":"yu0Mbf","breweryID":"v0MKXA"},{"beer":"Pumpkinhead Ale","rate":"3","id":"TlBAjN","breweryID":"5N0usi"},{"beer":"Punkin Ale","rate":"4","id":"hGjIJg","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Racer 5 IPA","rate":"3","id":"o1OELJ","breweryID":"5tw2Iw"},{"beer":"Raging Bitch Belgian IPA","rate":"4","id":"P203ye","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Raison DEtre","rate":"3","id":"Q4Ah1v","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Ranger","rate":"3","id":"iaYJ7X","breweryID":"Jt43j7"},{"beer":"Rare Vos","rate":"3","id":"OMyQoC","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"beer":"Rayon Vert","rate":"4","id":"vMm0Rc","breweryID":"Nj8cgD"},{"beer":"Red Sky at Night","rate":"3","id":"QWYlpK","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Reds Rye PA","rate":"3","id":"FOC78c","breweryID":"Idm5Y5"},{"beer":"Robust Porter","rate":"4","id":"fkylQX","breweryID":"v0MKXA"},{"beer":"Ruination IPA","rate":"4","id":"7cnuJq","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Sah'tea","rate":"4","id":"dc6ShA","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Saison du BUFF","rate":"3","id":"CTbk45","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Saison Rue","rate":"4","id":"V0T8uP","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"beer":"Samuel Adams Boston Lager","rate":"3","id":"z4k3eU","breweryID":"1wSztN"},{"beer":"Samuel Adams Octoberfest","rate":"3","id":"Hyyhug","breweryID":"1wSztN"},{"beer":"Samuel Adams Summer Ale","rate":"3","id":"DiBfxM","breweryID":"1wSztN"},{"beer":"Samuel Adams Winter Lager","rate":"2","id":"4fM6Pf","breweryID":"1wSztN"},{"beer":"Sapporo Premium Beer","rate":"2","id":"TOHi4D","breweryID":"D61TcY"},{"beer":"Schwartz Bier","rate":"3","id":"y4THvR","breweryID":"iw1hDB"},{"beer":"Shock Top","rate":"2","id":"v7H1Ev","breweryID":"BznahA"},{"beer":"Sixty-One","rate":"4","id":"L1eJ2p","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Small Craft Warning","rate":"3","id":"2qHZyl","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Smoking Wood","rate":"5","id":"8NX7Sy","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"beer":"Snake Dog","rate":"3","id":"Blig3z","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"Snow Pants","rate":"4","id":"g8oVuV","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"beer":"Sofie","rate":"4","id":"KBQTlS","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Son of a Peach","rate":"4","id":"94Fe7D","breweryID":"bWL816"},{"beer":"Squall IPA","rate":"4","id":"LZmXC8","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Stella Artois","rate":"3","id":"Jc7iGI","breweryID":"mIWMKP"},{"beer":"Stone IPA","rate":"3","id":"PAM6wX","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Stone Levitation Ale","rate":"4","id":"OaZYgf","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Storm King Imperial Stout","rate":"4","id":"4M26ru","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Sublimely Self-Righteous Ale","rate":"4","id":"SAtbDP","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"beer":"Summer Love Ale","rate":"3","id":"SzhLvG","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Summer Shandy","rate":"2","id":"nJjPsG","breweryID":"ZDghkK"},{"beer":"Summertime","rate":"3","id":"tXTETf","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"beer":"Sunset Amber Ale","rate":"4","id":"scC0RX","breweryID":"xcKkLh"},{"beer":"Sweet Baby Jesus!","rate":"4","id":"opSf4n","breweryID":"TVgBWg"},{"beer":"Sweet Child of Vine","rate":"3","id":"xrLwng","breweryID":"5GoGSi"},{"beer":"ta henket","rate":"4","id":"icSARl","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Tank 7 Farmhouse Ale","rate":"3","id":"lDiXyX","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"beer":"Ten Fidy","rate":"5","id":"x6bRxw","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"beer":"The Cask","rate":"3","id":"NgxwRi","breweryID":"dwroV3"},{"beer":"The Fear","rate":"2","id":"0ZX12D","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"The Libertine","rate":"4","id":"irF7Mh","breweryID":"5GoGSi"},{"beer":"The Sixth Glass","rate":"4","id":"zrAAHP","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"beer":"The Truth","rate":"3","id":"o9TSOv","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"beer":"The Vermonster","rate":"2","id":"UJI7C4","breweryID":"LpX3cU"},{"beer":"Theobroma","rate":"0","id":"H1L7UE","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Third Shift","rate":"3","id":"g284jn","breweryID":"avMkil"},{"beer":"Thomas Jefferson's Tavern Ale","rate":"3","id":"xDzvQP","breweryID":"jwWiTH"},{"beer":"Three Philosophers","rate":"4","id":"TOzkLy","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"beer":"Torpedo Extra IPA","rate":"3","id":"JaS6T7","breweryID":"nHLlnK"},{"beer":"Trade Winds Tripel","rate":"4","id":"jdulDH","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"beer":"Tribute Tripel","rate":"5","id":"FdRZ7e","breweryID":"UbQHhM"},{"beer":"Troegenator Double Bock","rate":"3","id":"OGlmOC","breweryID":"n5QFi2"},{"beer":"Tweasonale","rate":"3","id":"Qx1hbt","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"UFO White","rate":"3","id":"cG83LQ","breweryID":"RzvedX"},{"beer":"Unfiltered Wheat Beer","rate":"3","id":"lgaPWe","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"beer":"Unibroue 17","rate":"4","id":"VfyYpZ","breweryID":"llbEuB"},{"beer":"Urkontinent","rate":"3","id":"XQyXhk","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Vanilla Porter","rate":"3","id":"Bk34Go","breweryID":"IImUD9"},{"beer":"Vanilla Stout","rate":"4","id":"NRhCm4","breweryID":"oBe8dQ"},{"beer":"Walkers Reserve","rate":"3","id":"JgdTCV","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"beer":"Wells Banana Bread Beer","rate":"4","id":"hQzCbn","breweryID":"6oEP92"},{"beer":"West Coast IPA","rate":"4","id":"RC4BkU","breweryID":"Nj8cgD"},{"beer":"Western Rider","rate":"2","id":"ymabSa","breweryID":"bRKIdZ"},{"beer":"Winter Storm - Category 5 Ale","rate":"3","id":"fA0O8C","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"beer":"Wookey Jack","rate":"3","id":"f5DoHi","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"beer":"World Wide Stout","rate":"4","id":"H5sA73","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"beer":"Yakima Glory Ale","rate":"3","id":"q7dLm5","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"beer":"Yeti Imperial Stout","rate":"5","id":"oz1oll","breweryID":"I8WZv2"},{"beer":"Yuengling Traditional Lager","rate":"3","id":"wd1Y84","breweryID":"pX8lES"}]
```

Adapter code:

```
public class ShortBeerInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShortBeerInfo>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<ShortBeerInfo> data = null;

    public ShortBeerInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<ShortBeerInfo> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        beerHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new beerHolder();
            holder.txtBeer = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryName);
            holder.txtRate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.breweryRate);
            holder.txtBar = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.starbar);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (beerHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        ShortBeerInfo beer = data.get(position);
        holder.txtBeer.setText(beer.beer);
        holder.txtRate.setText(beer.rate + " out of 5.00 Stars");

        holder.numHolder= Float.parseFloat(beer.rate);

        holder.txtBar.setNumStars(5);
        holder.txtBar.setRating(holder.numHolder);

        return row;
    }

    static class beerHolder
    {
        TextView txtBeer;
        TextView txtRate;
        RatingBar txtBar;
        Float numHolder;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your onPostExecute function, are you sure you are not throwing an exception? If one is thrown, you silently swallow it. Can you try rethrowing the exception and see if anything happens?

Also, you are recreating the adapter several times in your loop.  It shouldn't cause an issue, but it won't help anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't see the list properly because your ListVew is within a ScrollView. ListView itself is scrollable , so it doesn't show properly in a ScrollView , you can at most see a ListView with very small height that fits one or two elements. Try using your ListView outside of ScrollView to test whether your code is correct or not. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds GREAT ! Good start of the day :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your doing it wrong.

You should be asynchronously loading the data into a sqlite db table and using a Loader with a cursor adapter.

Also, even using the code you have (and its hard to read from my phone here) it looks like your only adding one element to the list before you add the list adapter to the list view, which would be why you are only seeing a single item.

Another thing that may be causing you trouble is that you're asynchronously loading the data into a list view that has been created but you don't seem signal that the adapter has new data as the task finishes.

Comment: I have used similar code before and its worked just fine. I have a loop that goes through all the elements so I do not understand why only one gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code for the adapter so that it is outside and below your for loop. You are creating a new adapter for every iteration and it is probably running really slow because of it. Also you are setting your onitemclicklistener for every iteration too. It only needs to be done one time.

Do that and then see what happens. Also put a breakpoint after the for loop and see how many items are in your tasteList. If there is more than one then your adapter is most likely the problem.

If you can post your code for your adapter.

I guess my answer is that you probably aren't returning back more than one item. Since the adapter is posting data to the list it should be ok. Once you can debug the app and see how many items are returning then we can know for sure.

Comment: moving the adapter and onclick outside the for loop did not fix anything. I also added the adapter code to the above question.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint after your for loop and see how many items are in your list?

Comment: You need to debug your application. It's the little bug icon at the top of your eclipse, next to the play button. Add a breakpoint by double clicking the left bar of your editor at the line you need to. Code execution will stop and then you can hover your mouse over your tasteList and see how many times are there.

Comment: I would learn how to debug your app before you move any further.